# Why am I getting a " bad instruction " error?

Tags: swift

I have tested putting correct and incorrect indexes in when I call the function, and have figured out that only the second if-statement is what is causing problems. I'm not sure what to do since both of the if-statements are so similar I can't find the problem. I reset the second if statement to change changeThis to just the number one, that didn't work either so i just changed it back to aWordCharacters.count method... please help!!

```
// to define a custom index, and asign it a new custom position

func rearangeALetter( aWord: String, var changeThis: Int, var withThis: Int) -> (codedWord:String, fromTo: String) {
    let aWordCharacters: [Character] = wordSeperator(aWord)
    let changeCharacter: Character = aWordCharacters[changeThis]
    var finalWord: [Character] = aWordCharacters

    finalWord.removeAtIndex(changeThis)

    if withThis > aWordCharacters.count {
        withThis = 0
    }

    if changeThis > finalWord.count {
        changeThis = aWordCharacters.count
    }

    finalWord.insert(changeCharacter, atIndex: withThis)

    let returnWord = combineWords(finalWord)

    return (returnWord, "Letter number \(changeThis + 1) has been switched with letter number \(withThis + 1 )")
}

rearangeALetter("Hello", changeThis: 101, withThis: 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid range of indexes in an array is from 0 to count - 1, not from 0 to count.  I think you need to change the second if to:

```
if changeThis > finalWord.count {
    changeThis = aWordCharacters.count - 1
}
```

but, that said, I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, so I won't swear to it.  It also doesn't look like it actually will fix a crash since you don't actually use `changeThis` to index into the array.

Ah, you also need to do the bounds checks (both if statements) before you use the indices:

```
func rearangeALetter( aWord: String, var changeThis: Int, var withThis: Int) -> (codedWord:String, fromTo: String) {
    let aWordCharacters: [Character] = wordSeperator(aWord)

    if changeThis > finalWord.count {
        changeThis = aWordCharacters.count
    }

    let changeCharacter: Character = aWordCharacters[changeThis]
    var finalWord: [Character] = aWordCharacters

    finalWord.removeAtIndex(changeThis)

    if withThis > aWordCharacters.count {
        withThis = 0
    }

    finalWord.insert(changeCharacter, atIndex: withThis)

    let returnWord = combineWords(finalWord)

    return (returnWord, "Letter number \(changeThis + 1) has been switched with letter number \(withThis + 1 )")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm a beginner so this helps a lot. I'm simply making functions that manipulate strings to test my knowledge with swift. If that brings to mind any other suggestions, thank you very much again!